# Fourier Coefficients of periodic function

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Consider a Function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$. Is there any lower bound for the decay of the Fourier coefficients

$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt$$
 known?

There are a lot of upper bounds known but i cant find anything about a lower bound.

I would appreciate if you can help me!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by lower bound?

Comment: BTW welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: I mean the following: $ |\hat f(n)|\ge g(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, where $g\in o(n!)$ for example.

Comment: more precisely i am concerned about the coefficients of a function $f^{-1}$, where f is a polynomial.

Comment: you can invert them more or less explicitly, the case of roots with $\vert z_0 \vert  < $ or $ >0$ slightly different.  you often see this done in time series classes. The resut is coefficients of $\frac 1 f $ exponential in root or reciprocal roots.

Comment: actually you're probably better off using countour integration to get the asymptotocs, tho the result is the same: that they are controlled by the closest zeros to the unit circle.

Comment: So, $f$ is the reciprocal of a (trigonometric or algebraic?) polynomial. This information certainly belongs in the post, because the question is trivial ("$0$ is the best lower bound you can have) without such information about $f$. As it stands, we still don't know enough to give any nontrivial bound: if $f=[1+\text{(some tiny polynomial terms)}]^{-1}$, then $\hat f(n)$ is tiny for $n\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 3.2.2. in [Grafakos's book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=wd864jh25DQC&pg=PA2&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) *Classical Fourier analysis* (page 176) states that given a sequence $(d_n,n\geqslant 0)$ which converges to $0$, we can find an integrable function $f$ such that $|\widehat{f}(n)|\geqslant d_n$.